# Initialize database through sequelize on electronjs app startup

Tags: electron, sequelize.js, electron-packager

I am building a desktop app using electronjs and sequelize as ORM. The database I am using is sqlite3. I want to generate database schema as soon as user installs and runs the app. Currently I have added required sql scripts in migrations folder and also added '**sequelize db:migrate && electron .**' in the start script in package.json. If I execute *npm start* on my dev environment then the database schema is created successfully but when I run it with production installer it is not creating. 
I am using electron packager for packaging the app

Comment: That's because the app you're executing after you've packaged it is not using the scripts used in the `package.json`. That file's just for NPM and will not even be included in your packaged app.

Comment: Thank you verymuch @AlexanderLeithner! Do you have any idea how to achieve the db creation on startup of packaged app?

Comment: How about executing it from your app's code, and not from the command line? There's some useful guidance how to do that correctly in [their docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)...